# UITableView XML Parser

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, uitableview

The data comes smoothly.

But problems have Turkish characters.

Should come as "Düzce" but "ÜZCE" comes.. And,

"Akçakoca" cell in view "çakoca" comes..

XML URL : http://bykrkc.com/test.xml

XMLParser.m;

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "XMLFlightList.h"

@implementation XMLParser
@synthesize ucakList = _ucakList;

NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSXMLParser *parser;
XMLFlightList *currentFlight;
bool isStatus;

-(id) loadXMLByUrl:(NSString *)urlString{
    _ucakList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString * dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  error:&error];
    NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    parser =[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;

    //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data];
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"sehirler"])
    {
        currentFlight = [XMLFlightList alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if(isStatus){

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"ad"]){
            currentFlight.name = currentNodeContent;
        }

    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"sehirler"]){
        [self.ucakList addObject:currentFlight];
        currentFlight =nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

XMLParser.h;

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (strong,readonly) NSMutableArray *ucakList;
-(id) loadXMLByUrl:(NSString *)urlString;
@end
```

Result;

```
2013-12-18 15:49:21.505 tableview01[7663:70b] ÇORUM
2013-12-18 15:49:21.507 tableview01[7663:70b] İSTANBUL
2013-12-18 15:49:21.507 tableview01[7663:70b] ÖMERLİ
2013-12-18 15:49:21.508 tableview01[7663:70b] ÜZCE -> Problem True: DÜZCE
2013-12-18 15:49:21.508 tableview01[7663:70b] çakoca -> Problem True: Akçakoca
2013-12-18 15:49:26.156 tableview01[7663:70b] ÇORUM
```

Result Images: http://oi42.tinypic.com/2z9mgza.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in `-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` method. This method can be called more then once for each tag.
Try change your code:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
  if (currentNodeContent == nil) currentNodeContent = [NSMutableString new];
  [currentNodeContent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
```

As alternative you can use [XMLConverter](https://github.com/rsoldatenko/XMLConverter) for converting your XML to `NSDictionary`.

This code :

```
[XMLConverter convertXMLURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bykrkc.com/test.xml"] completion:^(BOOL success, NSMutableDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
  NSArray *elements = dictionary[@"DocumentElement"][@"sehirler"];
  for (NSDictionary *dic in elements) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dic[@"ad"]);
  }
}];
```

executed with result:

```
2013-12-18 18:00:46.037 test[690:70b] ÇORUM
2013-12-18 18:00:46.038 test[690:70b] İSTANBUL
2013-12-18 18:00:46.038 test[690:70b] ÖMERLİ
2013-12-18 18:00:46.039 test[690:70b] DÜZCE
2013-12-18 18:00:46.039 test[690:70b] Akçakoca
```

Comment: Not working :(  `[currentNodeContent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    NSLog(@"%@", currentNodeContent);` but `2013-12-18 16:28:40.790 tableview01[8320:70b] (null)`

Comment: @alikarakoc yes, second problem in `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName` method, in line `currentNodeContent = nil;`. Try use updated code.

Comment: @alikarakoc and may be third problem in `-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`. You must use `currentFlight = [[XMLFlightList alloc] init];` or `currentFlight = [XMLFlightList new];` instead of `currentFlight = [XMLFlightList alloc];`